# Arduino Out nodes won't connect in Node-red

Tags: arduino-uno, node-red

I have an arduino Uno connected to my notebook through an USB cable. I have uploaded the "Firmata Standard" example to the arduino. The node-red seems to be detecting the Arduino fine in COM5 but still when it keeps trying to connect to the pins but is never able to.
It was working fine for some nodes before, some couldn't connect but others could. Now no one of them is connecting.
[image: node-red interface, with a flow containing arduino out nodes that keep trying to connect, but do not get to]

I'm sorry for the low quality of the images. But there are 4 arduino out nodes that keep "connecting" and some other inject and function nodes.

Here's the view of one of the arduino out nodes setting:

[image: arduino out node setting]

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Please do not post photos of screens, if you really must post screen shots take them natively (the `prt sc`button will do this on nearly every OS). What is in the Node-RED logs, it will be logging why it is failing to connect.